# If $y=x{\int_0^x}\frac1{1+e^{x^2t^2}}dt$, what is $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

If $\displaystyle y=x{\int_0^x}\frac1{1+e^{x^2t^2}}dt$, by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Chain rule:

$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}={\int_0^x}\frac1{1+e^{x^2t^2}}dt+\frac{x}{1+e^{x^4}}$

So far, how to calculate $\displaystyle{\int_0^x}\frac1{1+e^{x^2t^2}}dt$ ? Or, is there any way to find $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: In order to differentiate an integral like that you need to use the
[Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule): $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(x,t)\,dt = f(x,x)+\int_a^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)\,dt.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=xt$,

$$y={\int_0^{x^2}}\frac1{1+e^{u^2}}du$$

Use Fundamental theorem of Calculus, we get

$$y'=\frac{2x}{1+e^{x^4}}$$